# Extreme points if $n \geq 2$: $X = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid a^\top x = b\}$

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming

I'm trying to delve into the lovely world of linear programming and have been confronted by a small confusion. If we let

$$X = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid a^\top x = b\}$$

and $a$ in the set Real vectors of length $n$, and $b$ in the set of real numbers...
how do we prove that $X$ will have no extreme points if $n \geq 2$. I understand the logic with straight lines, but I'm really not too sure how to go about proving it.
Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Use $\geq$ instead of >=

Comment: Thank you; I will learn how to do that. Sorry!

Comment: I guess $X$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^n$.